# Retrieving data from JSON data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following JSON data from my API

```
[{"email":"user@gmail.com","status":"Active"}]
```

This is the **JS/jQuery** code I am using to get the data

```
function formLogin() {
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    var dataString = "email=" + email + "&password=" + password;

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/OnlineShop/API/fetch_user_login_api.php",
        data: dataString,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#login-form").html(data);
            console.log('success');
            //window.location.href = "store.html?shopper=";

            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            alert(obj.email);

        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

`alert(obj.email)` is throwing undefined. How do I retrieve the email and status from the JSON result?

Comment: check your console for error

Comment: as you mentioned in your question. Your data is already in `JSON`. why are your parsing it again to `JSON`?

Comment: Did you mean JSON.parse(data) ?

Comment: a PHP page is passing it back in JSON, so want to use the returned response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "data" variable is already an object or an array, you don't need to call parseJSON.

Then, it seems that your object is an Array of objects
This should work:

```
 alert(data[0].email);
```

I advice you to check if your array is empty or not before calling this line.

Comment: this may be the reason. but he is parsing JSON to JSON, mention that too

Answer (score 0):

The API returns `[{"email":"user@gmail.com","status":"Active"}]` as it is of type Array.

first you need to take the first element of the Array by `obj = obj[0]`.

then it is something like `{"email":"user@gmail.com","status":"Active"}`.

now you can get the email element by simply `obj["email"]`

Answer (score 0):

if you call your api and get the result like this:

```
[{"email":"user@gmail.com","status":"Active"}]
```

it's an array, what you can do to fix the error is:

1) change your api response structure to JSON not array

2) use for to iterate your response

And I advice you next time, you have this kind of error, just console.log the raw data to find what's the structure of it, and you'll have the solution.